# Cannot add item to JS Map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, dictionary

I'm simply trying to add an item to a Map (like dictionary) in Javascript. I'm using React Native.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  AppRegistry,
  View,
  Button,
} from 'react-native';

export class Stack extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      statelist: new Map(),
    }
  }

  add_func_list() {
    let plist = new Map()
    plist.set(1, 'ddd');
    alert(JSON.stringify(plist))   
  }

  add_state_list(){
    let statelist = this.state.statelist
    statelist.set(2, 'ggg');
    this.setState({statelist})
  }

  render() {
      return (
          <View>
              <Button title="add to func list" onPress={this.add_func_list} />
              <Button title="add to state list" onPress={this.add_state_list} />
          </View>
      );
  }
}

export default function App(props) {
  return (
      <Stack />
  );
};

AppRegistry.registerComponent('default', () => App);
```

If you press the first button I'm adding to a local variable in a function. Nothing gets added, the alert shows {}

The second button should add to a state variable, but I'm getting an error:
"TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.statelist')

Any ideas?

Comment: map is not stringifiable

Answer (score 1):

The second error is due to code error:

```
onPress={this.add_state_list.bind(this)}
```

or convert the method to a arrow function.

Regarding the alert you can't Stringify it. its data is in prototype.
Map is an iteratable.
you can do :

```
alert(plist.size);
or
alert(plist.get('2'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  add_func_list() {
    let plist = new Map()
    plist.set(1, 'ddd');
    alert(JSON.stringify(plist.get(1))   
  }
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answer with an explanation are usually of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Sure I will explain.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Mukesh and Vivek. I'm new to RN so I wasn't aware of the restriction in printing a map. I actually have a bind of the method in my constructor, but failed to copy it into the example. Unfortunately the consequence was that it generated the same error as I have in my real system and I got fooled. Anyway, you answered the questions as I posted them, for which I'm thankful.
What turned out to be the real problem was a consequence of inheritance, and as I'm learning now inheritance of state doesn't work like other inheritance.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  AppRegistry,
  Button,
  View,
} from 'react-native';


export class Stack extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      statelist: new Map(),  // get's overwritten and destroyed by child state assgnment
    }
    //this.statelist = new Map(),  <-- this way it works fine if child sets state
    this.add_state_list = this.add_state_list.bind(this)
  }

  add_state_list(){
    this.statelist.set(2, 'ggg');
    alert(JSON.stringify(this.statelist.get(2)))   
  }
}


export class StackHandler extends Stack {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    // if I remove this.state assignment below, it works
    this.state = {
      count:0  // destroys parent's state
    };
  }

  render() {
      return (
          <View>
              <Button title="add to state list" onPress={this.add_state_list} />
          </View>
      );      
  }
}

export default function App(props) {
  return (
     <StackHandler/>
  );
};

AppRegistry.registerComponent('default', () => App);
```

This code corresponds better to my problem. Class StackHandler and class Stack both have state variables. Stackhandler inherits Stack. When Stackhandler sets its state variable, it destroys the state of its parent. For us with OOP background this seems counter-intuitive. Either way, I now know not to do this and can work around it. If anyone has a good explanation, I'm all ears. In any case I'm unstuck now!